# how to use a pretrained model on Tensorflow mobile android application?

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, machine-learning, yolo

I am trying to use the tensor flow mobile demo application on Android for image detection and classification following this [tutorial](https://github.com/nicolefinnie/TFdetect/blob/master/README.md?fbclid=IwAR0S-UWDTUbXcbBwxHohZFRwt2OeitD_w_De2oBk-M0Pg4Za96gPyDbdOqY). I think the app is using the inception model and I want to use another pre-trained model " ssd_mobilenetv2_oidv4 " from this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md). I do not have a lot of experience with machine learning but what I want to do is to replace the model that was used in the application with the mobilenetv2 model since it was trained on more class.

I have tried to copy the files in the pre-trained model to the assets folder in the application and adjust the path in the application but the problem is that the 2 models have different formats (i think) so the app crashes before it even starts.

the files in the assets folder (inception model):
 `imagenet_comp_graph_label_strings.txt`
`multibox_location_priors.txt`
`tensorflow_inception_graph.pb`
`tiny-yolo.pb`

MObilenetV2 the files in the model i want to use:
`checkpoint`
`frozen_inference_graph.pb`
`model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001`
`model.ckpt.index`
`model.ckpt.meta`
`pipeline.config`
`and folder "saved_model" containing:`
`a- saved_model.pb`
`b- an empty folder named "variables"`

so how do turn the model I want to use to the same format as the model in the assets folder (inception model)

Answer (score 0):

Note when you restore checkpoint files you dont have to initalize them beforehand.

`tf.train.Saver` can also restore (`tf.train.Saver.restore`):

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver#restore

Comment: can you elaborate more on that ? i don't really understand what the files represent!

Answer (score 0):

problem here is you're trying to use different model formats. To be able to use models from [model zoo detection repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) 
You should follow TensorFlow Lite example from this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android)
Also don't forget, that if you don't use tflite model, you should convert model to tflite. As an example, you can use this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@teyou21/convert-a-tensorflow-frozen-graph-to-a-tflite-file-part-3-1ccdb3874c4a)